# Consuming json object send by get method in jersey in java

Tags: json, angularjs, jersey, jax-rs, jersey-2.0

I try to consume java jersey web service from angular js . below part of conroller whose call ws

```
    UserService.getProfilUser(GLOBALS.DEFAULT_CLIENT_IP,JSON.stringify($rootScope.user),JSON.stringify($rootScope.magasins[0])).then(function(response){
         $scope.profilUser=response;
})
```

Below the getProfilUser function in UserService

```
 this.getProfilUser=function(clientIP,user,magasin)
    {
        var deferred=$q.defer();
        $http.get(url+'user/getUserProfil?clientIP='+clientIP+'&user='+user+'&magasin='+magasin).success(function(response){
            deferred.resolve(response)
        }).error(function(err){
            deferred.reject(err);
        })

        return deferred.promise;
    }
```

On my server side  and where I have a problem, I use @BeanParam to map my Json object with my bean
below the code of `getUserProfil` ws

```
@GET
@Path("getUserProfil")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Profil getUserProfilWithRCAccess(@QueryParam("clientIP")String clientIP, @BeanParam User user,@BeanParam Magasin magasin){

    System.out.println("ClientIP "+clientIP);
    System.out.println("User "+user.getEmploi());
    System.out.println("Magasin "+magasin.getLbMaga());
}
```

But

```
 System.out.println("User "+user.getEmploi())==>null 
 System.out.println("Magasin "+magasin.getLbMaga())==>null
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using

```
@QueryParam("clientIP")String clientIP
```

for `clientIP`, and you are setting the user and magasin

```
getUserProfil?clientIP='+clientIP+'&user='+user+'&magasin='+magasin
```

what makes you think it would be correct do use `@BeanParam`. Please see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29590487/2587435) for how to correctly use this annotation. It is not to magically turn JSON to a POJO.

`@QueryParam` is meant for [query string](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string) values, and that's exactly what you have. And with that annotation, you can only inject a String (that's why `clientId` is fine), unless you have

- A constructor in your bean class that accepts a String, or
- A static `fromString(String)` method that returns your bean type, or
- A static `valueOf(String)` that returns the bean type, or
- A `ParamConverter` for the bean type.

See [more about that here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29208992/2587435). In any of the cases, you are going to need to parse the JSON yourself, most likely using some JSON to POJO framework like Jackson. Here is [another good article](http://blog.dejavu.sk/2014/02/11/inject-custom-java-types-via-jax-rs-parameter-annotations/) for using a `ParamConverter` for you use case.

#### *Another thing...*

Your method is for a `GET` request. You cannot `@Consumes` anything. That is for the `Content-Type` of the body of the request. GET requests have no body. That is meant mainly for `@POST` and `@PUT` request. In which case you will have a completely other problem.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Before my ParamConverter class implementation I was able to consume webservice who take as parameter a simple string , but after the creation and register of class ParamConverter in my application as it explain inside the article in your answer, I'm not able to consume these webservice . It's it a manner to specify in ParamConverterProvider class or web service to  convert ? . Sorry If my question is stupid, but I'm new in jersey rest implementation.

Comment: You might need to Url encode the JSON. With Javascipt [`encodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent). Are you getting some exceptions?

Comment: If you are getting the JSON string OK, then try to use the `ObjectMapper` directly in your resource method, just to see if it works, `User user = new ObjectMapper().readValue(userString, User.class);`. If that works, then just add a `public static User fromString(String userString)` in the `User` class, and return the value from the ObjectMapper parsing. I don't know why the paramconverter is not working. I would need to test the whole thing, which I don't have time to do right now.

Answer (score 1):

I'm also new to REST and jersey and trying to learn. As I understand the above discussion, I think the way you are implementing is not right. You want to send the JSON object(user&Magasin) as query parameter and in jersey want to use as `@BeanParam`
As I read about the BeanParam the way of doing is, it take the value from the jsp form and set to bean (Book) and this bean is pass as @BeanParam.

Here the example [BeanParam Example](http://java.dzone.com/articles/new-jax-rs-20-%E2%80%93-beanparam)

Might be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

As already explained. You have a json string and you want to build an object. Please transform the json to object with a json parser.

Here is how to do so :

```
@GET
@Path("getUserProfil")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Profil getUserProfilWithRCAccess(@QueryParam("clientIP")String clientIP, @QueryParam("user") String userJson, @QueryParam("Magasin") String magasinJson){

    Gson gson  = new Gson();
    Magasin magasin = (Magasin) gson.fromJson(magasinJson, Magasin.class);
    Usermagasin = (User) gson.fromJson(userJson, User.class);


    System.out.println("ClientIP "+clientIP);
    System.out.println("User "+user.getEmploi());
    System.out.println("Magasin "+magasin.getLbMaga());
}
```

Please use the Gson librairy :

if you user maven : 
    
        com.google.code.gson
        gson
        2.3.1

Or add to your webapp this jar in the dependencies : http://central.maven.org/maven2/com/google/code/gson/gson/2.3.1/gson-2.3.1.jar

Comment: Thanks for your anwser but my parameters are `Bean` not `String`